# Kafka Stream partition distribution

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In `Kafka Stream`, `stream tasks` will be distributed between instances in multi-instance(and hence `partitions` will be distributed). On the other hand, one of differences between `KTable` and `GlobalKTable` is that `KTable` distributes `partitions` between instances(**from** *Mastering Kafka Streams and ksqlDB*).

Now I can't understand that `KTable` will eventually cause distribution or `Stream Task` or both(If both, then how)?

What happened if we have `KTable` in our `topology` and multiple `stream task`(source processor on a multi-partition topic) in a multi-instance environment?

Answer (score 0):

Sure sure if I fully understand the question. Maybe the docs help to shed some light: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/architecture.html

A `KTable` (and `KStream`) is a logical abstraction. When you call `streamsBuilder.build()` it will be compiled into a `Topology` with `Processors`. Connected `Processors` (that may have a state store attached) are grouped into sub-topologies, and sub-topologies are executed by tasks (base on the number of partitions).

For `streamsBuilder.table("topic")`, the compiled `Topology` is:

```
topic -> source -> processor(state)
```

For each topic partition, a task will be created processing one partition, and thus the `KTable` is implicitly partitioned, too.

Comment: I read it before, but I could not to understand this. I'll read it again. Thanks @Matthias j. Sax